# SpriteKit - Changing anchorpoint on node changes position of all childnodes

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm so freaking confused about anchorpoint in SpriteKit.

If I have a Node consisting of multiple childnodes, and I change the anchorpoint of the Node, then all the childnodes gets misplaced. Is there any way around this?

I think it's really annoying to position nodes if I always use the default anchorpoint (0.5,0.5), so sometimes I change the anchorpoint to for example 1.0,0.0 so it's easily placed in the right lower corner. But if this node has childnodes, then they are all misplaced when I change the anchorpoint.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Avoid changing the default anchorPoint whenever possible.
2. If you do change anchorPoint, make sure you do so only on nodes without children.

In your case (and in general) the fix is relatively easy. Instead of adding child nodes to the sprite node whose anchorPoint got changed, use a common parent node (SKNode). Add the sprite node to the parent node, change the sprite's anchorPoint but don't add any children to it. Instead add those children to the parent node. You can then use the parent node to position this branch of the node tree together.

Alternatively create a subclass of (or category on) SKSpriteNode with methods that allow you to align the node to a certain border, taking the sprite's frame size and anchorPoint into account. For example you could add two properties verticalAlign and horizontalAlign with center, left/top and right/bottom alignment. Whenever the position property is changed, the point is offset before being passed to super setPosition so that the alignment mode is adhered to.

Comment: Is this a bug with anchorPoint ?

Comment: Good question. The behavior is different than cocos2d, and I haven't done any tests to see how exactly anchorPoint changes affect child nodes. It seemed odd but there may be some logic to it after all.

Comment: I came to the conclusion at some point that maybe it was only to position the texture in a SKSpriteNode, but didn't dig too deep to verify that. I have been handling the situation as you have described.